# Getting error while running Sqoop in EC2 instance

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, sqoop

I installed Sqoop in my EC2 instance with the reference of http://kontext.tech/docs/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/p/configure-sqoop-in-a-edge-node-of-hadoop-cluster My hadoop cluster is also working well and good.

I got the error `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster` and I solved it with the mentioned solution given in that particular link. But unfortunately I get another error while running Sqoop Import:

`Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild`.

Please suggest me how to over come this error.

This is how my sqoop-env.template.sh looks:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# included in all the hadoop scripts with source command
# should not be executable directly
# also should not be passed any arguments, since we need original $*
# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.
#Set path to where bin/hadoop is available
#export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-3.1.0
#Set path to where hadoop-*-core.jar is available
#export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-3.1.0
#set the path to where bin/hbase is available
#export HBASE_HOME=
#Set the path to where bin/hive is available
#export HIVE_HOME=
#Set the path for where zookeper config dir is
#export ZOOCFGDIR=`
```

Comment: Is Hadoop installed where you're running Sqoop? If so, what Java CLASSPATH is being loaded?

Comment: Yes hadoop is installed and running well. I have set all the class path of java ,hadoop.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, but `"Could not find or load class"` suggests otherwise

Comment: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default

export JAVA_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

 this is the JAVA Path

Comment: That's the PATH for the OS... Not the CLASSPATH that Java loads classes from... Please add your `sqoop-env.sh`  file to your question

Comment: I have added the sqoop-env.sh. please suggest me what classpath to add.

Comment: Anyone who has come across this problem and solved it please help.

Comment: 1) Sqoop doesn't yet support Hadoop 3.x, as far as I know... 2) You need to remove the `#`  in front of `#export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME` and `#export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` 3) when it says `Set path to where hadoop-*-core.jar is available`... You need to do that - where you currently set that variable contains no jar files

Comment: Also, if you're in AWS, then I'm not sure why you're trying to do this all yourself rather than using EMR https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-sqoop-to-transfer-data-from-amazon-emr-to-amazon-rds/

Comment: Thank you so much. The hadoop 2.8.3 is a stable version and its working.